# How can I add a sort function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to add a sort function to my "Person Class". when I add new persons they are being appended to the "contacts" list and saved to a CSV file. I would like to be able to create a sort function sorting from A-Z. Any tips appreciated.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first, last, age, phone_number):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age
        self.phone_number = phone_number
 
    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first} {self.last}'
 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first} {self.last} : {self.age} : {self.phone_number}"
 
 contacts = list()
 
 if os.path.isfile("contacts.csv"):
    with open("contacts.csv") as f:
        csv_list = f.readlines()
        for contact_line in csv_list:
            contact_data = contact_line.rstrip().split(",")
            contact = Person(contact_data[0],
                             contact_data[1], 
                             contact_data[2],
                             contact_data[3])
            contacts.append(contact)
        
users_input = ""
```

Comment: So which `sort()` function were you thinking could be applied? Did you mean you want the list `contacts` sorting?

Comment: The sorting shouldn't be part of the class. That would make no sense since `contacts` is not an attribute of the class.

Comment: Something like `sorted(contacts, key=lambda person: (person.last, person.first))`?

Comment: I'm prompting the user to press a key with an assigned action. For eg. "Press 1" to add a contact, "Press 2" to display. I would like to say "Press 3 to Sort by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to pass a `key` to your sorting function.
Demo:

```
for contact in sorted(contacts, key=lambda x: x.full_name()):
    print(contact)
```

This will work flawlessly, and also works as `contacts.sort(key=lambda x: x.full_name())`. This is because you are telling the sort methods to sort using the full name of the person.

BUT a better and more robust way to make classes is to implicitly define how to compare objects of that class. You can do that as follows:

Define the `__lt__` (less than) method for your class objects which `sort()` and `sorted()` use by default. Then your objects can be compared with each other. Follow the code and the example below as a guideline:

Update class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first, last, age, phone_number):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age
        self.phone_number = phone_number

    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first} {self.last}'

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.full_name() < other.full_name()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first} {self.last} : {self.age} : {self.phone_number}"
```

My example contacts for demo:

```
a = Person("Bruce", "Wayne", 19, 22453)
b = Person("Tony", "Stark", 19, 22453)
c = Person("Clark", "Kent", 19, 22453)
d = Person("Steve", "Rogers", 19, 22453)
contacts = [a, b, c, d]
```

To show that less than indeed works and compares using full name:

```
Person("Bruce", "Wayne", 19, 22453) < Person("Tony", "Stark", 19, 22453)
```

Output: `True` (as expected alphabetically).

You can also add `__gt__`, `__ge__`, `__le__`, `__eq__` if required, but only `__lt__` is required for sorting.

Sorting:

```
for contact in sorted(contacts):
    print(contact)
```

Output:

```
Bruce Wayne : 19 : 22453
Clark Kent : 19 : 22453
Steve Rogers : 19 : 22453
Tony Stark : 19 : 22453
```

You can also permanently sort by doing `contacts.sort()`.
Pass the `reverse=True` keyword argument for reverse sorting.

NOTE: you should take care of error handling when overloading operators, and raise appropriate errors. You can even do implementations for comparison of objects of various types. Like in this case, you might want to compare a person with a string (containing their full name), and want obj == str to return true if they match. You can do that too (leaving it as an exercise)

Comment: @ItchyPrune Happy to help. Consider accepting it as the answer if it helped you out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a `lambda` key for the builtin `sorted()` function, as has been pointed out in the comments. Another solution is to add the `__lt__` ('less than') and `__gt__` ('greater than') methods to your class. Adding these methods allows you to use the `<`, `>` and `==` operators between instances of your class, and tells Python's `sorted()` function how it should compare instances of the class by default.

The following code will cause Person instances to be sorted by last-names first, then first-names. If you want their default sort to be by first-names first, just reverse the order of the names in the `tupled_name` attribute I've added to the `__init__` method.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first, last, age, phone_number):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.tupled_name = (last, first)
 
    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first} {self.last}'
 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first} {self.last} : {self.age} : {self.phone_number}"

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Person):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.tupled_name < other.tupled_name

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Person):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.tupled_name > other.tupled_name

Alice = Person('Alice', 'Woods', 65, 123456)
Bob = Person('Bob', 'Alderman', 45, 123456)
print(Bob > Alice) # False: Alderman is earlier in the alphabet than Woods
print(Bob < Alice) # True: Alderman is earlier in the alphabet than Woods
print(Bob == Alice) # False: would have been True if they had the same full name, but they don't
list_of_people = sorted((Alice, Bob))
print(list_of_people[0].full_name()) # Bob Alderman -- comes first because his surname is earlier in the alphabet
print(list_of_people[1].full_name()) # Alice Woods
```

Answer (score -3):

I think it would be easier if you would split all the attributes into individual lists and then sort them like this

```
dict    = {'a': '00', 'b': '01', 'c': '02', 'd': '03', 'e': '04', 'f': '05', 'g': '06', 'h': '07', 'i': '08', 'j': '09','k': '10', 'l': '11', 'm': '12', 'n': '13', 'o': '14', 'p': '15', 'q': '16', 'r': '17', 's': '18', 't': '19', 'u': '20', 'v': '21', 'w': '22', 'x': '23', 'y': '24', 'z': '25', ' ': '26'}


first_name, last_name, attribute3, attribute4 = []

def sort():
    i=0
    while i<len(first_name)-1:
        if int(dict.get((first_name[i]))) > int(dict.get(first_name[i+1])):# can change this statement to sort by which ever attribute you want
            a = first_name.pop(i)
            b = last_name.pop(i)
            c = attribute3.pop(i)
            d = attribute4.pop(i)
            first_name.insert(i + 1, a)
            last_name.insert (i + 1, b)
            attribute3.insert(i + 1, c)
            attribute4.insert(i + 1, d)
            sort()
        i+=1
sort()
```

using the dictionary to compare the letter values, you might need to do a bit of string slicing. but this should work and if you really needed the multidimensional array you can form it after the sort

here is the simpler sort function if you want to mod it yourself

```
def sort():
    i=0
    while i<len(arr)-1:
        if arr[i]>arr[i+1]:
            a = arr.pop(i)
            arr.insert(i+1,a)
            sort()
        i+=1
sort()
print(arr)
```

Comment: This will return in a `TypeError` because Python doesn't know what part of the `Person` class to compare.

Comment: And how do you expect `sort` to know which attribute(s) of the `Person` instances it should use for the sorting?

Comment: Is there a way to specify to sort by first name, last name etc?

Comment: do all 4 attributes need to be sorted and preserve the order?

Comment: To keep it simple lets say no. Just a simple sort from A-Z of Last names?